# Scrapy is sending response of type None to my custom file pipeline

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Using Scrapy, I want to download & save the files with different filename.

First of all, if I enable the default files pipeline. The files (may be html/pdf) are downloading perfectly fine.

For renaming, I wrote the following class & overriden `file_path` method.

```
class MyCustomFilePipeline(FilesPipeline):
    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None, *, item=None):        
        # extract from 191148 http://mywebsite.com/filedownload.asp?pn=191148&yr=2022
        pn = re.search(r'(?<=pn\=)\d+', request.url).group()
        print(f'{request.url} - {pn}')
        print(type(response)) # <-- this prints as <class 'NoneType'>
        
        response_contentype = response.headers['Content-Type'].decode('ASCII')
        ext = 'html'
        if response_contentype  == 'text/html':
            ext = 'html'
        elif response_contentype == 'application/pdf':
            ext = 'pdf'
        print(f'{pn}.{ext}') # <-- this is not printed  
        return f'{pn}.{ext}'
```

I enabled it in settings.py. In the console, for each request URL, I'm getting the output of both the print statements (in the above code, for debugging).

But the `response` is `<class 'NoneType'>`.

Surprisingly, `print(f'{pn}.{ext}')`  isn't being printed.

No files are begin downloaded. `files` is not populated

Why isnt the scrapy making requests & getting responses? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

1. you are not seeing `print(f'{pn}.{ext}')` is because response is None and `response.headers` is an error and it's stopping the rest of the code.
2. Why is response None: because if you check the code for [FilesPipelines](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/078622cfb0ee364acba5d91a20244f9c1ee87d30/scrapy/pipelines/files.py#L294) the function filepath is executed twice twice once in [media_to_download](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/078622cfb0ee364acba5d91a20244f9c1ee87d30/scrapy/pipelines/files.py#L385) without response (that's why you were getting None) and once in [media_downloaded](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/078622cfb0ee364acba5d91a20244f9c1ee87d30/scrapy/pipelines/files.py#L436) with the response.

one way to make your code work although i don't know if it's the best solution is to wrap your code with `if response`

```py
class MyCustomFilePipeline(FilesPipeline):
    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None, *, item=None):
        if response:
            # extract from 191148 http://mywebsite.com/filedownload.asp?pn=191148&yr=2022
            pn = re.search(r"(?<=pn\=)\d+", request.url).group()
            print(f"{request.url} - {pn}")
            print(type(response))  # <-- this prints as <class 'NoneType'>
            response_contentype = response.headers["Content-Type"].decode("ASCII")
            ext = "html"
            if response_contentype == "text/html":
                ext = "html"
            elif response_contentype == "application/pdf":
                ext = "pdf"
            print(f"{pn}.{ext}")  # <-- this works now
            return f"{pn}.{ext}"
```

Comment: Thanks. That's helpful. Regarding point 1. Then why isn't the error thrown to the console?  How are we to debug such hidden errors? Is there any better way apart from scattering print statements all through out?

Comment: I also found it weird that we didn't get an error, maybe we should raise the problem to the scrapy team